# RxJava: UndeliverableException when flatMap combined with switchMap

Tags: rx-kotlin, rx-java3

## TL;DR

I think that `flatMap` combined with `switchMap` might not terminate the stream correctly, thus `UndeliverableException` happens. How can I fix this?

## The Structure

I'm making a little bit complex stream -- combined with `flatMap` and `switchMap` -- like below, in RxKotlin (RxJava 3):

```
someObservable
    .flatMapMaybe {
        if (matchCondition(it)) Maybe.just(it)
        else Maybe.never()
    }.flatMapSingle {
        procedureMiddle(it) // Inconsistent-time-consuming Single
    }.switchMap {
        procedureLater(it)
    }.doOnError {
        dealWithError(e)
    }.retry()
    .subscribeBy(
        // ...
    )
```

The `procedureMiddle` inside `flatMapSingle` has a chance of returning Error in the end.

## The Exception

It turns out that sometimes the error from `procedureMiddle` might jump out of structure, not being ignored by `retry`, nor dealt in `dealWithError` in `doOnError`:

```
W/System.err: io.reactivex.rxjava3.exceptions.UndeliverableException: The exception could not be delivered to the consumer because it has already canceled/disposed the flow or the exception has nowhere to go to begin with. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling | my.custom.app.CustomException
// traces indicates that the Exception is thrown from inside procedureMiddle
```

## The Question

In fact the `UndeliverableException` doesn't really cause crash, but it's a little bit annoying for me --especially it looks like a situation I need to handle. However I thought the structure is correctly written? So here's my question:

1. Does `switchMap` really (correctly) terminate the last stream from `flatMap`? (And can be used to prevent `UndeliverableException`?)
2. If so, at which part of code I should adjust? If not so, how could I prevent the exceptions along with my structure? (I want to concat `procedureLater` after `procedureMiddle`, and keep only latest one)

Any suggestion or explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The [RxJava2 Official Doc](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What%27s-different-in-2.0#error-handling) explains a few about `UndeliverableException`:

> `UndeliverableException`: wraps the original exception that can't be delivered due to lifecycle restrictions on a `Subscriber` / `Observer`.

So it, actually, does NOT mean that your code have any problems (directly). It just reminds you that some streams still throw error after you ended/canceled/disposed them.

About the question:

> Does `switchMap` really (correctly) terminate the last stream from `flatMap`? (And can be used to prevent `UndeliverableException`?)

- Yes, it terminates the last stream.
- And NO. `UndeliverableException` would still happen. Because it terminates the last stream, so if the last stream throws error, the error would be wrapped and thrown as `UndeliverableException`.

> If so, at which part of code I should adjust? If not so, how could I prevent the exceptions along with my structure?

You don't need to adjust the code, nor preventing `UndeliverableException`, as it always have a chance to come up when disposing/cancelling/ending any streams (manually or even automatically.)

I suggest just ignoring it:

```
RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler {
    if (it is UndeliverableException) {
        // This happens when throwable comes out AFTER subscription is canceled or disposed.
        // Not what we care about as it is likely disposed by user or system.
        Log.d(
            "Application", "UndeliverableException: ignored.\n" +
                    "$it: problem ${it.cause} / ${it.cause?.message}\n" +
                    "at ${it.cause?.stackTraceToString()}"
        )
        return@setErrorHandler
    }
    // other Exceptions: do some report
}
```